# How can I have an asterisk to an author’s name in the bibliography but not in the text?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-ext

For some publication entries it is important to pass along the information of "shared last authorship" and/or "equal contribution".

I can get this using `author+an` and a redefinition of `mkbibfamily`. This works great, but I also have the asterisk of the author’s name in text. But I only want to have it in the bibliography.

I was wondering if there is a boolean like `when-in-bibliography` or any idea, how this could be solved.

Here is my MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bib.bib}
@String {equal = {\textit{*equal contribution}}}
@String {sharedlast = {\textit{*shared last authorship}}}

@Article{roessner2021a,
  Author          = {Roessner, P.M. and Cid, L.Llao and Lupar, E. and Roider,
                    T. and Bordas, M. and Schifflers, C. and Arseni, L. and
                    Gaupel, A.C. and Kilpert, F. and Krotschel, M. and
                    Arnold, S.J. and Sellner, L. and Colomer, D. and
                    Stilgenbauer, S. and Dietrich, S. and Lichter, P. and
                    Izcue, A. and Seiffert, M.},
  Date            = {2021},
  author+an       = {17=sharedLast;18=sharedLast},
  Addendum        = sharedlast,
  Title           = {{EOMES} and {IL}-10 regulate antitumor activity of T
                    regulatory type 1 {CD4(+)} T cells in chronic lymphocytic
                    leukemia},
  Volume          = {35},
  Pages           = {2311--2324},
  JournalTitle    = {Leukemia}
}


@Article{sackett2019a,
  Author          = {Sackett, Sara Dutton and Otto, Tobias and Mohs, Antje
                    and Sander, Leif E. and Strauch, Sonja and Streetz,
                    Konrad L. and Kroy, Daniela C. and Trautwein, Christian},
  Date            = 2019,
  Title           = {Myeloid cells require gp130 signaling for protective
                    anti-inflammatory functions during sepsis},
  Volume          = 33,
  author+an       = {1=equal;2=equal},
  Addendum        = equal,
  Pages           = {6035--6044},
  DOI             = {10.1096/fj.201802118r},
  JournalTitle    = {The FASEB Journal},
  Number          = 5
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-ecomp,
  autocite=inline,
  defernumbers=true, % reset numbered bibliography for each chapter
  giveninits=true, % abbreviate the first names
  maxcitenames=1,
  mincitenames=1,
  maxbibnames=99, % show all authors of an bib entry
  ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

% There is also the possibility that authors share the last authership.
% with the bib-string `lastShared` we can get it work.
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{equal}
    {#1*}% add a * for those authors
    {%
    % Then we check for "shared Last authorship"
    \ifitemannotation{sharedLast}%
    {#1*}% adding a symbol
    {#1}% do nothing for any one else.
  }}

\begin{document}
\autocite{roessner2021a,sackett2019a}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hide the asterisk in a macro that can have different behavior according to the context, using a toggle that can be set to true in the bibliography using the `\bibsetup` hook.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@String {equal = {\textit{*equal contribution}}}
@String {sharedlast = {\textit{*shared last authorship}}}

@Article{roessner2021a,
  Author          = {Roessner, P.M. and Cid, L.Llao and Lupar, E. and Roider,
                    T. and Bordas, M. and Schifflers, C. and Arseni, L. and
                    Gaupel, A.C. and Kilpert, F. and Krotschel, M. and
                    Arnold, S.J. and Sellner, L. and Colomer, D. and
                    Stilgenbauer, S. and Dietrich, S. and Lichter, P. and
                    Izcue, A. and Seiffert, M.},
  Date            = {2021},
  author+an       = {17=sharedLast;18=sharedLast},
  Addendum        = sharedlast,
  Title           = {{EOMES} and {IL}-10 regulate antitumor activity of T
                    regulatory type 1 {CD4(+)} T cells in chronic lymphocytic
                    leukemia},
  Volume          = {35},
  Pages           = {2311--2324},
  JournalTitle    = {Leukemia}
}


@Article{sackett2019a,
  Author          = {Sackett, Sara Dutton and Otto, Tobias and Mohs, Antje
                    and Sander, Leif E. and Strauch, Sonja and Streetz,
                    Konrad L. and Kroy, Daniela C. and Trautwein, Christian},
  Date            = 2019,
  Title           = {Myeloid cells require gp130 signaling for protective
                    anti-inflammatory functions during sepsis},
  Volume          = 33,
  author+an       = {1=equal;2=equal},
  Addendum        = equal,
  Pages           = {6035--6044},
  DOI             = {10.1096/fj.201802118r},
  JournalTitle    = {The FASEB Journal},
  Number          = 5
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-ecomp,
  autocite=inline,
  defernumbers=true, % reset numbered bibliography for each chapter
  giveninits=true, % abbreviate the first names
  uniquename=init,
  maxcitenames=1,
  mincitenames=1,
  maxbibnames=99, % show all authors of an bib entry
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand{\addendumasterisk}{\ifbibliography{*}{}}
%%% the following three lines commented out, see end of the answer
%\newtoggle{showasterisk}
%\newcommand{\addendumasterisk}{\iftoggle{showasterisk}{*}{}}
%\appto{\bibsetup}{\toggletrue{showasterisk}}

% There is also the possibility that authors share the last authorship.
% with the bib-string `lastShared` we can get it work.
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{equal}
    {#1\addendumasterisk}% add a * for those authors
    {%
    % Then we check for "shared Last authorship"
    \ifitemannotation{sharedLast}%
    {#1\addendumasterisk}% adding a symbol
    {#1}% do nothing for any one else.
  }}

\begin{document}

\autocite{roessner2021a,sackett2019a}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

[image]

moewe, who's *the* `biblatex` wizard, suggests that the block

```
\newtoggle{showasterisk}
\newcommand{\addendumasterisk}{\iftoggle{showasterisk}{*}{}}
\appto{\bibsetup}{\toggletrue{showasterisk}}
```

can be replaced by the simpler

```
\newcommand{\addendumasterisk}{\ifbibliography{*}{}}
```

(added to the code above commenting out the original).

Comment: Thanks. the lines `\newrobustcmd{\equalcontribution}{\textit{*equal contribution}}
\newrobustcmd{\sharedlastauthorship}{\textit{*shared last authorship}}` are not necessary?! It is the same content as in the bibstring!?

Comment: @lukascbossert Leftover from a previous attempt.

Comment: `biblatex` has the tests `\ifbibliography` and `\ifcitation` that can be used to test the "context". In this example we could replace `\iftoggle{showasterisk}` by `\ifbibliography`, but this may not be useful if a more intricate logic is desired.

Comment: The syntax is `\ifbibliography{<true>}{<false>}` (analogous for `\ifcitation`).

Comment: I knew I have read this `\ifbibliography` somewhere but couldnt find it anymore in the documentation. Thanks alot!